# Converting String from Command Line to Binary - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a String inputted as a number in the command line and then convert that string into a binary via a method. Then, return the string method back to main and display the output as a string representative of a binary. I am receiving some error messages, any help is much appreciated:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Lab04.decimalTobinary(Lab04.java:20)
    at Lab04.main(Lab04.java:13)

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;

public class Lab04
{

public static void main(String[] args) { 

  String d_s = new String(); // stores command line input argument
  args[0] = d_s;
  String b_s = new String();

  b_s = decimalTobinary(d_s); // decimalString from command argument 

  System.out.print(b_s);
} 

public static String decimalTobinary(String decimal) { 

    int n = Integer.parseInt(decimal);
    String s = "";

    while (n > 0)
    {
        s =  ( (n % 2 ) == 0 ? "0" : "1") +s;
        n = n / 2;
    }
    return s;
} 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the assignment operator in a wrong way: the intention was to assign `args[0]` to `d_s`, not the other way round.

There's also no need to initialize variables to "dummy strings" - you can assign the "correct" values directly.

The `main` would become:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

  String d_s = args[0]; // stores command line input argument

  String b_s = decimalTobinary(d_s); // decimalString from command argument

  System.out.print(b_s);

}
```

Comment: Alex, thank you for helping me. I greatly appreciate it. V/R, Austin